# Lambda function only putting one data point into InfluxDB

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, influxdb, influxdb-2

I have a Lambda function that is designed to take a message from a SQS queue and then input a value called `perf_value` which is just an integer. The CloudWatch logs show it firing each time and logging `Done` as seen in the `.then()` block of my write point. With it firing each time I am still only seeing a single data point in InfluxDB Cloud. I can't figure out why it is only inputting a single value then nothing after that. I don't see a backlog in SQS and no error messages in CloudWatch either. I'm guessing it is a code issue or InfluxDB Cloud setup though I used defaults which you would expect to actually work for multiple data points

```
'use strict';

const {InfluxDB, Point, HttpError} = require('@influxdata/influxdb-client')

const InfluxURL = 'https://us-west-2-1.aws.cloud2.influxdata.com'
const token = '<my token>=='
const org = '<my org>'
const bucket= '<bucket name>'

const writeApi = new InfluxDB({url: InfluxURL, token}).getWriteApi(org, bucket, 'ms')

module.exports.perf = function (event, context, callback) {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  let input = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].body);
  console.log(input)

  const point = new Point('elapsedTime')
    .tag(input.monitorID, 'monitorID')
    .floatField('elapsedTime', input.perf_value)
    // .timestamp(input.time)
  writeApi.writePoint(point)
  writeApi
  .close()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Done')
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.error(e)
    if (e instanceof HttpError && e.statusCode === 401) {
      console.log('Unauthorized request')
    }
    console.log('\nFinished ERROR')
  })

  return true
};
```

EDIT**
Still have been unable to resolve the issue. I can get one datapoint to go into the influxdb and then nothing will show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Joshk132 -

I believe the problem is here:

```
writeApi
  .close() // <-- here
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Done')
  })
```

You are closing the API client object after the first write so you are only able to write once. You can use `flush()` instead if you want to force sending the Point immediately.